# Why can't rust compiler deduce from splitting stdin lines

Tags: ubuntu, compilation, rust

I am very new to rust, and I'm trying to make a programme that reads stdin, splits each line based on the `,` character and prints the first item (a simple CSV-like / unix programme).

This is the programme and the compiler error is below.

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut stdin = io::stdin();

    for line in stdin.lines() {
        let fields = line.unwrap().as_slice().split_str(",").collect();
        print!("{}", fields[0]);
    }
}
```

And I get this error:

```
groupby.rs:12:22: 12:31 error: the type of this value must be known in this context
groupby.rs:12         print!("{}", fields[0]);
                               ^~~~~~~~~
```

I have no idea what's going on, nor why this doesn't work. Shouldn't it be obvious (to the compiler) that `fields` is now a Vec of strings(-type things)?

This is rustc 0.12.0-pre from the Ubuntu nightly PPA (201409260407~bb66281 )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from `collect()`. [`Iterator::collect()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#tymethod.collect)'s return type is generic: it can be any type that implements [`FromIterator<T>`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html). `Vec<T>` is such a type. You simply need to add a type annotation:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut stdin = io::stdin();

    for line in stdin.lines() {
        let line = line.unwrap(); // must bind the result of unwrap()
                                  // to fix a lifetime error
        let fields: Vec<&str> = line.as_slice().split_str(",").collect();
        print!("{}", fields[0]);
    }
}
```